# Excel Formula for Defining Range for COUNTIF value in Dynamic Data

Tags: excel, range, countif

The scenario...

1. The Excel file is generated from dynamically loaded data into an Excel table.
2. One column has a value that is associated with a group of records.
3. The group of records can range from a single record to dozens.
4. A second column has a variety of meta-data values.
5. Next column contains a formula to identify if a given meta-data value exists in the rows of the group. EXAMPLE: [NON-HUMANS] =IF(COUNTIF(RANGE,"<>HUMAN")>0,"YES","NO")

*NOTE - The group value correlates to a UUID of which there are hundreds, for the sake of simplifying the sample data, I have used ALPHA, BRAVO, CHARLIE, ETC.*

The issue - as the number of group records varies, I need to define the range in the formula based on the GROUP column value.

SAMPLE DATA SET

```
GROUP,MEMBERS,SPECIES
ALPHA,Scooby,DOG
ALPHA,Shaggy,HUMAN
ALPHA,Velma,HUMAN
ALPHA,Daphne,HUMAN
ALPHA,Fred,HUMAN
BETA,Alvin,CHIPMUNK
BETA,Simon,CHIPMUNK
BETA,Theodore,CHIPMUNK
CHARLIE,Superman,HUMAN
CHARLIE,Batman,HUMAN
CHARLIE,Robin,HUMAN
CHARLIE,Wonder Woman,HUMAN
CHARLIE,Aquaman,HUMAN
CHARLIE,Wonder Dog,DOG
DELTA,Spider-Man,HUMAN
DELTA,Ice-Man,HUMAN
DELTA,Firestar,HUMAN
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have <kbd>Excel O365</kbd> then you can utilize `XMATCH()`. Try-

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUM(--((INDEX($C$2:$C$18,XMATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$18,0,1)):INDEX($C$2:$C$18,XMATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$18,0,-1)))<>"HUMAN")),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Not yet, being rolled out soon.